# ASP.NET Authentication and Provider

Tags: asp.net, authorization, sqlmembershipprovider

I am trying to navigate from one website on my localhost to second website on my localhost.

Both sites have their own membership provider.  I'm trying to use a FormsAuthorizationTicket from site #1 to SSO a user into site #2.

Currently I'm getting this error:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Steps I have taken up to this point include:
   Setting the  element to specific key values
   Set the machineKey attributes of validation and encryption to "3DES"
   Verified through logging that the encrypted ticket has the same value in the #2 website as it was given in the #1 website.

---

My code is here:

```
        *FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
        FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new 
            FormsAuthenticationTicket(1 // Ticket Version
            , Login1.UserName                       // User Name
            , DateTime.Now                          // Creation Date
            , DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)   // Expiration Date
            , true                                              // Is Persistant
            , Login1.UserName);                 // This should be a list of Roles


        string strEncyptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("cryptCookie", strEncyptedTicket);
        myCookie.Values.Add("username", Login1.UserName);
        myCookie.Values.Add("cryptTick", strEncyptedTicket);
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);*
```

---

In website #2 I created a landing page to verify the ticket and redirect to a members only page.  During decryption is when I get the error specified above.

Here is my landing page code on website #2:

---

```
        *FormsAuthenticationTicket fat2 = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies["cryptCookie"].Values["cryptTick"]);


        MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(Request.Cookies["cryptCookie"].Values["username"]);
        if (mu == null)
        {
            lblInfo.Text += "member not found";
            return;
        }

        Response.Redirect(@"~\MemberPages\MemberPage.aspx");*
```

If anyone has an idea to help I'll be happy to try.

Answer (score 1):

Both sites need to share the same [machine key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx).

Comment: My machine key is defined in my machine.config file, which I believe is inherited by both web sites (since both are on my localhost).  Is there something else I need to do to meet that requirement?



  <machineKey decryption="3DES" 
     validationKey='123' 
     decryptionKey='123'
validation='3DES'/>

Comment: It was more of an observation than an answer. If your using the built-in IIS in VS (that localhost:3123/yoursite) I dont think they share cookies. In the long run, you'll have a problem crossing a domain (mysite1.com to yoursite3.net)

Answer (score 0):

Ian is correct in that your sites need to have a matching machine key.  Also, you need to make sure that your membership providers have the same setting, particularly concerning password encryption.

Also, why are you handling this completely in code?  You should be able to configure this functionality withing the Web.Config of both sites very easily.  In essence, you are doing a lot of rework and introducing potential problem areas where it is not necessary (unless you have reason that you have not stated here).

Comment: I'm handling this in code because I'm not sure how it is possible to do it in the web.config.  These are two separate websites, that will be on two different domains in the future with different membershipproviders.  Essentially I want to have Site #1 authorize a user, then pass a role value in the ticket so that site #2 will know what functionality to allow this user.  

From what I have read this cannot be handled in the web config.  Can you lead me to solving this in the web.config?

Comment: As Ian stated above, if your sites live on two separate domains (not just subdomains) you will not be able to share any cookies between them.